# Как сделать эффект такого треуголника в секции?

Tags: css

Как сделать эффект такого треуголника в секции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру так, естественно размеры определите для себя сами.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.with_triangle::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="with_triangle"></div>
```

А вот вариант от Сырка на бордерах, мне нравится меньше, т.к. цвет нужно задавать руками и этому объекту

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.with_triangle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="with_triangle"></div>
```

Comment: А на `border` треугольники рисовать не умеете?)

Comment: Нет. А как это можно сделать?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Если вопрос ко мне можно и бордерами, разницы нет, разве только он за объектом находиться не будет.